# Selecting related ids from database

Tags: php, sql

My database like this: table name: messages

```
| receive | transmit |
---------------------
|   1    |  5    |
|   1    |  6    |
|   1    |  3    |
|   3    |  1    |
|   4    |  1    |
|   2    |  3    |
|   4    |  6    |
|   7    |  9    |
```

How do i get all ids which are related to 1 but not to others from each column.

how do i get 3, 4 ,5 ,6  but not 2,7,9? Because they have nothing to do with '1'

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: `where 1 in (receive, transmit)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work :

```
SELECT receive
FROM messages
WhERE transmit = 1
UNION
SELECT transmit
FROM messages
WhERE receive = 1
```

Check the demo here : **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d1eb1/4/0)**

Comment: hum, you are true, i'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

In mysql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(receive = 1, transmit, receive) as id
FROM messages
WHERE receive=1 OR transmit=1
```

This will return a distinct list of all ids that have communicated with `1`, regardless of who the transmitter or receiver of the message was.